# blueimp Gallery borderless thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, css, blueimp

I am using blueimp Gallery on my site, but my thumbnails are shown with a white border. The live demo is shown with borderless, what should i change and where? I tried to make thumbnails with the same size as on the demo (86x86px), but doesn't solve my problem. I checked all the css's but didn't found the corresponding class/id.

[The live versions gallery (bottom of the page).](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/)
[image: My layout.]

http://theprob.wha.la/sample/ <- Uploaded a simple version of my site here!

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, jacascript, jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: Nobody can solve your problem by image.

Comment: @alirezasafian
You are right, i uploaded a sample version [here](http://theprob.wha.la/sample/), you can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `float:left;` to `a` element inside `#link1`.

```
#links1 a
{
  float:left;
}
```

Or use `display:inline-block;` and don't forget to [remove space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements#answer-5078297) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`

```
#links1 a
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one was the solution.

Comment: @BélaTóth You are welcom